# Eclipse, CDT, (N)Curses and debugin/profiling

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, valgrind, ncurses

**Hi!**

Is it possible to debug/profile a ncurses based application written in Eclipse\CDT? By using eclipse IDE of course.

Main problem is that eclipse to run this application should use a external console but it wont do that.
Even redirecting output into a file (terminal) didnt change anything...

For now Im using valgrind to looking for leaks and other things and its hard to read output file wich a single editor. Eclipse had a plugin for valgrind but it can not import resoult data for analise.

Here is my configuration:

- System Linux(Debian based)
- Eclipse IDE
- Valgrind as a profiler

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as the executable was compiled with debug symbols you can simply launch it in an external shell then attach the debugger after the process is up:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#Can_I_debug_a_process_that_I_didn.27t_develop_in_Eclipse.3F

On the screenshot by that FAQ item, you'll be interested in the "C/C++ Attach to Application" Launch Configuration.